# Servicestack-RabbitMq: Return response type in message headers

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

Is there any way to add the type of the response dto to the rabbitmq response message's headers collection?

(My consumer is using spring's rabbitmq handler which seems to depend on explicit type information inside the mq header when deserializing.)

Currently servicestack's mq producer already returns serveral headers, such as "content_type='application/json".

I am in need of an additional header, e.g. "**typeId**"="HelloResponse", so that the consuming web app knows how to deserialize the message, even in RPC cases where the response queue name is some kind of GUID.

Is there some kind of configuration which would enable me to archieve such an behaviour? Or some hook before the message gets published so that I can add the header myself?

Comment: Can you provide more context on how you're consuming the MQ Service? and at what point you need the type name. Are you reading from the message from the `mq:HelloResponse.inq`? in which case the Type is in the mq name.

Comment: We are not consuming the default response queue (e.q. mq:HelloResponse.inq), but a temporary queue (amq.*) instead. Therefore we cannot infer the response type from the response queue name. 
We need to provide a type name in order to pick the right json deserializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added support for automatically populating the Message Body Type in RabbitMQ's `IBasicProperties.Type` as well as adding support for both Publish and GetMessage Filters [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/9e5c19f1b1f84773b019cc85f812bbd2c461cd29).

Here's an example of configuring a `RabbitMqServer` with custom handlers where you can modify the message and its metadata properties when its published and received:

```
string receivedMsgApp = null;
string receivedMsgType = null;

var mqServer = new RabbitMqServer("localhost") 
{
    PublishMessageFilter = (queueName, properties, msg) => {
        properties.AppId = "app:{0}".Fmt(queueName);
    },
    GetMessageFilter = (queueName, basicMsg) => {
        var props = basicMsg.BasicProperties;
        receivedMsgType = props.Type; //automatically added by RabbitMqProducer
        receivedMsgApp = props.AppId;
    }
};

mqServer.RegisterHandler<Hello>(m => 
    new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, {0}!".Fmt(m.GetBody().Name) });

mqServer.Start();
```

Once Configured any message published or received will go through the above handlers, e.g:

```
using (var mqClient = mqServer.CreateMessageQueueClient())
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Name = "Bugs Bunny" });
}

receivedMsgApp.Print();   // app:mq:Hello.In
receivedMsgType.Print();  // Hello

using (IConnection connection = mqServer.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    var queueName = QueueNames<HelloResponse>.In;
    channel.RegisterQueue(queueName);

    var basicMsg = channel.BasicGet(queueName, noAck: true);
    var props = basicMsg.BasicProperties;

    props.Type.Print();   // HelloResponse
    props.AppId.Print();  // app:mq:HelloResponse.Inq

    var msg = basicMsg.ToMessage<HelloResponse>();
    msg.GetBody().Result.Print();  // Hello, Bugs Bunny!
}
```

This change is available from ServiceStack **v4.0.33+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).